# awk to delete even number file leaving odd number files

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to remove the `.bam` and `.bam.bai` if the digits after the `IonCode_` are even and keep the files if the digits after the `IonCode_` are odd. The `awk`  does execute but no files are printed. I added the `print` to verify but will delete them. Thank you :).

**awk w/ find**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | awk -F'[._]' '($NF=="bam" && !($(NF-1)%2)) || ($NF=="bam.bai" && $(NF-1)%2) {print "rm " $0}'
```

**files in directory**

```
IonCode_0241_19-000-Last-First.bam
IonCode_0241_19-000-Last-First.bam.bai
IonCode_0242_19-000-Last-First.bam
IonCode_0242_19-000-Last-First.bam.bai
```

**desired files remaining after script executed**

```
IonCode_0241_19-000-Last-First.bam
IonCode_0241_19-000-Last-First.bam.bai
```

Comment: Is the number always 4-digits?

Comment: yes it is always four digits. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include `.` as a possible field separator, so the last field cannot possibly *contain* a `.` – instead it's going to be `$NF == "bai" && $(NF-1) == "bam" && $(NF-2)...`.

There's a simpler option that doesn't involve awk:

```
rm IonCode_[0-9][0-9][0-9][02468]_*.bam
rm IonCode_[0-9][0-9][0-9][02468]_*.bai
```